# Rails actionMailer Message only has text/html MIME parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am using ActionMailer to send emails with rails with a third-party SMTP server, the email is always falling into the spam folder (when sending to gmail addresses), I contacted the support and they tested using mail-tester.com which indicates that there is the following issue:

```
Message only has text/html MIME parts
You should also include a text version of your message (text/plain)
```

In my mailer views I have only the html files, but when I look at Devise mailer I see that they have the same thing, there is not text version, so I am a little confused, what should I do in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my answer as usual ;)

As best practice:

**First:** make sure your Html emails are wrapped in an html tag, or better use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- your html email here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**Second:** in plus of your every html email file, add an equivalent file with `.text.erb` extension, for example if you have a mailer file called `reset_password.html.erb` then make sur you add another one `reset_password.text.erb` that contains only plain text (No html tag ever!).

With that, if the receiver doesn't use HTML email, the text version of your email will be used.

**Here is an example how to turn one of devise html template to plain text:**

HTML version (confirmation_instructions.html.erb):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

    <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

    <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Text version (confirmation_instructions.text.erb):

```
Welcome <%= @email %>!

You can confirm your account email through the link below:

<%= confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>
```

**Note also** how I changed:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>
```

To:

```
<%= confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>
```

Because **link_to** will generate `<a>` tag which we don't want to have in a text email.